# How to get row index value in crystal reports?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, report

In crystal reports oncrviewer doubleClick event, I need to get rowindex of the row was clicked at run time:

```
private void crystalReportViewer1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int j = 0; j <= CRP.Database.Tables[0].Fields .Count - 1; j++)
    {    MessageBox.Show(CRP.Rows[**RowIndex**].DataRowView.Row.ItemArray.GetValue(j).ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to retrieve the value of a Crystal Report Field in a row when you click the row? For example, if you click a row with an "Employee Name" field, are you able to retrieve that employee's name as a string? If so, this will be easy:

Calculate the row number *inside the report* as a Running Total or Formula (or even a Shared Variable) then simply retrieve that value when the row is clicked. Additionally, you can suppress the counter field in the report, and even though it's invisible it shouldn't affect your ability to retrieve the info.

Comment: @EmadHosni No worries! Be sure to mark the answer as Accepted if it was in fact the answer you needed.